# Nginx cache to serve cached content instead of error pages

Tags: nginx, cache

Is there any way to configure Nginx to serve cached content instead of error pages?

Let's suppose that accessing a page `/abc.html` resulted in 200 and the page was cached. Meantime something changed (the file was deleted or, if nginx is used as a reverse proxy there is a 50x server error etc) and instead of serving the error, I would like to serve the last "good" cached page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nginx is [fully capable](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule) of caching proxied (or fastcgi) content. In this case you will want to adjust your [`proxy_cache_use_stale`](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_cache_use_stale) directive (or [`fastcgi_cache_use_stale`](http://nginx.org/r/fastcgi_cache_use_stale)) to reflect the circumstances in which you want to serve cached data.